# Checking textbox value against javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a quick question and I feel like I might just be missing something easy.

I currently have an array of codes below the document ready function of my jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
var code = ['code', 'code', 'code', 'code', 'code', 'code', 'code', 'code', 'code', 'code', 'code', 'code', 'code', 'code', 'code', 'HG3BV', 'code', 'code', 'code', 'code', 'code', 'code'];
"use strict";
```

This is at the top of my js document.

Then down further I check on my forms if it finds a class value of validate-required2 and if it does, I want it to check the value of the textbox #codes against my array.

```
            $(form).find('.validate-required2').each(function() {
            var cheater = $('#codes').val();
              if (jQuery.inArray(cheater, code)!='-1') {
                $(this).removeClass('field-error');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('field-error');
                error = 1;
            }
        });
```

However this is constantly returning that the values aren't in the array.  Did I miss something easy here?

Comment: put your `code` array declaration outside `$(document).ready`, before it.

Comment: Is the code in the same case as the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to write

```
var cheater = $(this).val();
```

if the selector `'.validate-required2'` refers to your `input`-elements. Your original selector can only get you *one*  value in total since the id referred to (`'#codes'`) *must* be unique on your page.

Comment: I actually just forgot to change the id on my input box to codes which was a really dumb thing of me to do but your answer works too!